# Why it doesn't crash when invoking a nonexistent api

Tags: android

I am running such a code piece on an Android emulator with api level 16:

```
package darklord.compilesdkversiontest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
        int result = linearLayout.getPaddingEnd();
        Log.e("Test", result+"");
    }
}
```

The getPaddingEnd is added in api level 17 so I am expecting this to crash on the emulator. There is indeed a warning in the Android Studio however it did compile and runs on the emulator. Furthermore, it even prints out the correct padding value. So why it doesn't throw some runtime expection? Here is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "darklord.compilesdkversiontest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: I pulled out the /system/framework/framework.odex from the emulator and converted it to a jar. The LinearLayout.getPaddingEnd is really not there.